# I want to ask grammar about gerunds

Tags: gerunds

1.The purpose of the first paragraph is to provide details necessary to understanding the story.

I don't understand "necessary to understanding the story", it should be "necessary to understand the story", shouldn't it?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjectives like 'necessary' -- those expressing importance, necessity, or urgency -- are not followed by an -ing form. OALD gives the following:

> Necessary **for** somebody / thing

And

> Necessary **to do** something

NECESSARY is followed by an infinitive. (We could also insert 'for' + a noun or pronoun, followed by an infinitive.)

*"The purpose of the first paragraph is to provide details necessary to understand the story."* (Here, 'to' isn't a preposition; it's infinitive 'to'.)

Or,

*"The purpose of the first paragraph is to provide details necessary **for us** to understand the story.*

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that "understanding" can be the gerund of the verb *to understand*. Gerunds are very useful because, by making the verb into a noun, it can be used as the subject or object of a sentence.

However, a gerund is normally used with a possessive noun or pronoun - for example "*my understanding is...*" or "*the current understanding is...*". In your example, there is no possession of the "understanding". It isn't a gerund, but the *present participle* of the verb. This has been used to show the *ongoing* understanding as one reads the story. The statement is saying that, if you have read the first paragraph of the story, you will understand *as you read*.

The statement works just as well with "understand", but to understand something means to fully comprehend it, and arguably you cannot say you understand a story unless you have completed it. When we say that we understand something at a midway point it tends to mean that we understand *so far*.